# How to setup Jenkins build with two separate repositories (poms)?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

My project structure looks as follows:

Core

- pom.xml

Project A

- pom.xml

Project B

- pom.xml

Core, Project A, Project B are separate git repositories. I need this structure because all of my Projects should use the same core settings (and when I have to change something in the core, all Projects are updated without having troubles).

I haved added the following dependency to the Project (Project A + Project B) pom:

```
<!-- Core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>my-group</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-core</artifactId>
  <version>${my-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In eclipse on my local machine it works like a charm. The project finds the core and i am able to run all of my selenium tests.

Now I want to setup jenkins and one jobs should contain Project A + Core, another job Project B + Core - but I have no idea how to do that. I have already searched for some solutions, but I dont want to setup a Nexus for example. So is there a easy way to include my core + project in jenkins?

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843696/checkout-multiple-git-repos-into-same-jenkins-workspace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538198/jenkins-multiple-git-repositories-for-one-project

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) to retrieve all repositories into job's workspace and then:

1. Build and install core project using maven's `install` lifecycle (so, `my-core` becomes available in local maven repository on Jenkins machine).
2. Build Project A
3. Build Project B

Comment: Sounds easy. Do you know a good how-to because I am not very familiar with Jenkins / Multiple SCMs Plugin. Its my first time I am working with Jenkins - I have already set up one project with only one pom, but thats it.

Comment: Yes, that's easy. First you need to install that plugin. Then you will have a [following](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/b018fb45aa2671350c730b6daf53d62e1.png) radio button. Just add 3 git repositories and do the same thing you already did, but for each repo.

Comment: @taddeuz does this help ?

Answer (score 0):

In the SCM section of the Jenkins job configuration screen, choose 'Multiple SCMs'. You'll then see a drop-down list of the available SCM plugins which can be configured similar to the way build steps are configured for a freestyle job. When chosen, each SCM plugin will present its normal set of configuration options.

Make sure each SCM checkout is done in a separate sub-directory of the workspace to avoid conflicts between the SCM providers. If using Mercurial, this option is hidden in the 'Advanced' section, so don't forget to configure it.

If changing the SCM provider for an existing job, I recommend wiping out the workspace.