# How can i trigger a Jenkins jobs by pulling 2 different branches?

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 different branches to be pulled from 2 different git projects, project1 has everything i need in branch A and project2 has everything i need in master, how can i get both ?

I tried to get 2 projects but jenkins is showing only 1 " Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') "option under branches to build

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843696/checkout-multiple-git-repos-into-same-jenkins-workspace ... As far as I am aware the answer given in this question is still correct with modern version of jenkins and the git plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) which is built for such cases.