# What's the best way to create/organize Jenkins projects?

Tags: jenkins

If anyone can make the tile better, please do it.

Take git for example, each repo/project has multiple branches, and we need to build each or some of branches. My questions is how shall we create Jenkins project to build these branches?

Currently I am using a "single Jenkins project + git Inverse strategy + conditional step" approach to build each repo, so it's one Jenkins project for one repo.

Another approach is create one Jenkins project for each branch, such as using GitHub Organisation Folder plugin.

What's the pros and cons, and are there any better approaches?

Comment: I think you can fin an answer here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843696/checkout-multiple-git-repos-into-same-jenkins-workspace?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843696/checkout-multiple-git-repos-into-same-jenkins-workspace?rq=1)