# Git Multiple Repositories clone and pull in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have 450 git repositories from single git server and we would like to clone them once and pull them (next time onward) in Jenkins for build purpose.

Configuring through Multiple-SCM Jenkins plugin is manual process, as each repository URL we need to input in that.
Therefore is there any other plugin available to put all my 450 repositories in one place (Or) any Command/script available for the same?
Kindly advise.

Comment: Google's `Repo` is very good at managing multiple repositories. Please see https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-repo/ where you can find how to install and use it. You may also need https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [Checkout multiple git repos into same Jenkins workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14844316/6309), you nowodays (2017) needs to use [Pipeline+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) in order to build multiple Git repo in the same job.

The idea behind pipeline is that you can store it as a [*file* (called jenkinsfile)](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) in its own Git repo and define *one* Jenkins job (type "pipeline"), which will look for that Jenkinfile

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43273518/6309) using the `dir` basic step:

```
dir: Change current directory
```

> Change current directory.
>   Any step inside the `dir` block will use this directory as current and any relative path will use it as base path.

That same example uses [gradle](https://gradle.org/) which knows how to [build multiple projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

The [OP Mohan S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4948798/mohan-s) used the [`-C` option I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115526/6309):

> The following command worked.

```
git -C mohan_test pull || git clone -b mohan_branch --single-branch ssh://mohan.s@100.101.102.103:29418/mohan_test mohan_test –
```

Comment: The following command worked.    git -C mohan_test pull || git clone -b mohan_branch --single-branch ssh://mohan.s@100.101.102.103:29418/mohan_test mohan_test

Comment: @Mohan.S Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. (As well as a link to the `-C` option)