# Have 2 directories in a Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to pull 2 git repository in a single Jenkins job but in 2 different directories, how to achieve it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a pipeline script (Jenkinsfile) or configuration via UI?

Comment: Configure via UI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkout multiple git repos into same Jenkins workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843696/checkout-multiple-git-repos-into-same-jenkins-workspace). As you can see there, you probably should use a pipeline script instead (2nd edit)